# Orthogonal diagnoal Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm having problem for orthogonal diagonalization a matrix.

A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}

I want to know what I'm doing wrong. So in order to find this kind of matrix I need to get to this step: 
$P^{-1} A P$

Now, I need to find the characteristic polynomial which is
$p(x) = -x^3 + 3x - 2x = 0$

therefore $x = 2, 1, 0$

What is the next step?

Comment: @Amzoti - 
What is GS?

Comment: @Amzoti Oh, I now that onw. So what shoud I do next in order to find the orth. diag. matrix of this given matrix? the GS?

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1) Find an eigenvector for each of those three eigenvalues

2) Apply Gram-Schmidt to the above three vectors (why is it possible? Say, why are they linearly independent?)

3) Now form $\;P\;$ with the orthonormalized basis as columns

4) You're done.

Comment: And P will be the orth.diag. matrix, right?

Comment: Well, its columns are orthonormal vectors...so yes!

Comment: @DonAntonio, since all eigenvalues are distinct and $A$ is symmetric, you don't need Gram-Schmidt here, just normalization.

Comment: Please check me: P i've got is: [000//000//010]. Am I right?

Comment: @New_Math_, $P$ should be invertible.

Comment: Yes indeed, @user35603. Good point.